# How to parse list of jsons in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a list of jsons associated to an ID that I need to parse out in BigQuery. Not too familiar with creating UDFs or Javascript but here's my attempt

The data is structured in two columns, one being ID and the second a json string:
`[{"date":"2019-12-07","amount":10},{"date":"2019-12-08","amount":20,{"date":"2019-12-09","amount":30},{"date":"2019-12-10","amount":40}]`

My ideal output is something like:

```
id        date     amount
10     2019-12-07    10
10     2019-12-08    20
10     2019-12-09    30
10     2019-12-10    40
```

Here is my SQL so far:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(input STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<date DATE>
LANGUAGE js AS """
return JSON.parse(input);
""";

select
  t.id,
  trim(t.inputs,'[]')
from test t
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have well defined strings, using SQL-only will give you faster and more scalable results:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION sql_parse(str STRING) AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(date, amount))
  FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, '"date":"([-0-9]*)') dates, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, '"amount":([0-9]*)') amounts
  ), UNNEST(dates) date WITH OFFSET i, UNNEST(amounts) amount WITH OFFSET j WHERE i=j
));


WITH input AS (
SELECT 10 id, '[{"date":"2019-12-07","amount":10},{"date":"2019-12-08","amount":20,{"date":"2019-12-09","amount":30},{"date":"2019-12-10","amount":40}]' x)

SELECT id, date, amount
FROM input, UNNEST(sql_parse(x));
```

[image]

For better JSON-arrays support in BigQuery, upvote this:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63716683

Comment: The CREATE TEMP FUNCTION statement is used to create a temp UDF in BigQuery. In both cases, the temp UDF contains the actions required to parse the data. You can only use temporary UDFs in a single query, whereas you can reuse persistent UDFs across multiple queries. You can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#temporary-udf-syntax) to see further details about the Standard SQL User-Defined Functions in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '[{"date":"2019-12-07","amount":10},{"date":"2019-12-08","amount":20},{"date":"2019-12-09","amount":30},{"date":"2019-12-10","amount":40}]' inputs
)
SELECT
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(item, '$.date') `date`,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(item, '$.amount') amount
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(JsonToItems(inputs)) item
```

with output

```
Row id  date        amount   
1   1   2019-12-07  10   
2   1   2019-12-08  20   
3   1   2019-12-09  30   
4   1   2019-12-10  40
```

Comment: The map() method in JavaScript creates an array by calling a specific function on each element present in the parent array. It is a non-mutating method. Generally map() method is used to iterate over an array and calling function on every element of array. You can google `javascript map` to get much more and with examples :o)